# Laravel - How can i show images with specified name from public folder?

Tags: php, image, laravel, directory

I want to display all images with specified id.

Ex: i just wanna display all images with same id before underscore.

how i do that?
I have this,

```
Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
{

    $path = public_path('uploads') . '/' . $filename;

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

But i want to change, instead of filename i want an id, and i wanna show all images start with that id

Note:Sorry, new here!

[image from folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNOB8.png)

Comment: share some code, what you have tried until now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Please take a look at id and edit your question. As Neetin said, show us what you've tried so far. Stackoverflow is here to help you, not to code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Php has a function named "glob" that can handle that.

```
$files = glob("uploads/".$id."_"."*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($files as $filename) {
  echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i got this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' " how can i solve it?

Comment: i have this: $files = glob("/public/uploads/".$id."_"."*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);   but returns : [ ]. in my route i have: return $files. is that right?

Comment: i changed to :  $files = glob("uploads/".$id."_"."*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE); and result : ["uploads\/1_0.jpg","uploads\/1_1.jpg"]

Comment: so it worked , cheers ... mark the answer as correct if it really helped you

Comment: yeah i will, Thank you very much! just one more question, now a have to do a foreach to go through and display images in $files?